# PHP : Recursively add parant child to the multi dimension array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, drupal-8

I have a function which gives an array of the below format

```
$result = [
      [
        "name" => "text",
        "id" => "928610",
        "entity_type" => "node"
      ],
      [
        "name" => "folder",
        "id" => "987620",
        "entity_type" => "folder"
      ],
      [
        "name" => "text",
        "id" => "956720",
        "entity_type" => "node"
      ],
];
```

Each Folder "entity_type" => "folder" item has again child which returns same format array.

like if we run a foreach loop $result and if it is "entity_type" => "folder" then we pass the id to a function it will also give a similar array format as that of result.

So i need if it is "entity_type" => "folder"  the below key added to the "entity_type" => "folder" item

```
"children" => [
  '#theme' => 'child_elements',
  '#child_elements' => [
    [
      'name' => 'text',
      "id" => "333421",
      "entity_type" => "node"
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'folder',
      "id" => "897622",
      "entity_type" => "folder"
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'text',
      "id" => "342214",
      "entity_type" => "node"
    ],
  ],
],
```

and recursively it should keep on adding if "entity_type" => "folder"

The final array should be

```
$result = [
      [
        "name" => "text",
        "id" => "928610",
        "entity_type" => "node"
      ],
      [
        "name" => "folder",
        "id" => "987620",
        "entity_type" => "folder"
        "children" => [
          '#theme' => 'child_elements',
          '#child_elements' => [
            [
              'name' => 'text',
              "id" => "333421",
              "entity_type" => "node"
            ],
            [
              'name' => 'folder',
              "id" => "897622",
              "entity_type" => "folder"
            ],
            [
              'name' => 'text',
              "id" => "342214",
              "entity_type" => "node"
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      [
        "name" => "text",
        "id" => "956720",
        "entity_type" => "node"
      ],
];
```

```
public function buildTree($elements) {

      $branch = []; 
      $branch = ['#theme' => 'child_elements'];
     
      foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {

        foreach($element as $keys => $values){  
            
          if ($element['bundle'] == 'folder') {              
              $child = $this->loadElements($element['id']);              
              $branch['#child_elements'] = $child;
              $element[$key]['children'] = $branch['#child_elements'];

              $this->buildTree($child);
              
              array_push($branch, $element);
              
                  
           }else{
              
              $branch['#child_elements'][] = $element;
           }
        }
          
        
      }

    return $branch;
    }
```

Comment: In your first $result array, when the loop gets to folder with "id" => "987620" = where do I look for the possible children? Are there other arrays?

Comment: I have attempted but the array is not as expected.

Comment: How do i achieve this

Comment: @SidharthSahu  - your attempt is an important part of the process. It shows that you've tried and aren't just asking for someone to figure it out for you. It shows us where your misunderstandings might be so we can help you where you need it. please post your attempt

Answer (score -2):

you need to use some logic statement  and use array_push when the condition is met.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: Huh? Anyways, I know you don't have the rep to post comments yet, but answer a few questions and you'll soon have enough to comment. When you post comments as answers (which you've done here), it makes it likely people will downvote it, which hurts your rep.